# Adapter getView() method is not accessed

Tags: android, adapter, getview

This is my adapter:

```
public GamblingVideoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GamblingVideosBean> gamblingVideosBeans) {
        this.context = context;
        this.gamblingVideosBeans = gamblingVideosBeans;
        Log.d("===GamblingVideoAdapter", "adaper text : " + gamblingVideosBeans.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return gamblingVideosBeans.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return gamblingVideosBeans.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d("===gambling", "adapter hi kevin");

        return null;
    }
```

This is what I get in the logcat:

```
    10-05 19:09:20.118 5925-5925/com.sb.android.acg.test I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
10-05 19:09:20.386 5925-7768/com.sb.android.acg.test D/===GamblingVideoAdapter: adaper text : 50
```

I tried all the answers given in Stackoverflow but none of them seems to solve my problem.

Comment: Please share the code, how you set the adapter to your ListView.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Kunu there is no error or exception

Comment: Your adapter is not extending any of Android List Adapter... basically your implementation will lead to NPE because you are returning a  null View. could you please post where your are setting the adapter to your ListView?

Comment: my guess is that `gamblingVideosBeans.size()` returns 0, so no views are created

Comment: Look at the logcat, the size is 50

Comment: did you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` ?

Comment: @AnisBENNSIR this is not the real code this is test i just wan to show log in getView inside logcat

Comment: @RuannReis yes i have tried it same issue

Comment: Can you post the entire adapter class?

Comment: @UmangBurman this is the entire adapter class

Comment: Try my solution.. is it extending any class?

Comment: @KevinKurien I think that your are not setting the adpater instance to your ListView. Are your sure that your adapter is attached to listView?

Comment: It doesn't extend ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        gamblingVideoAdapter = new GamblingVideoAdapter(GamblingVideosActivity.this, videosBeans);
        lvGamblingVideos.setAdapter(gamblingVideoAdapter);

    }
});
```